# Marshal.dump on an EmbeddedDocument with mongo_mapper does not work

Tags: ruby, mongomapper

I stumbled about a problem marshalling a MongoMapper::Document that has an embedded document. Here's the script:

```
# gem install mongo_mapper -v 0.13.0beta2
require 'active_support'
require 'mongo_mapper'

MongoMapper.database = "mmt"

class Foo 
  include MongoMapper::Document
  key :msg, String
  one :bar 
end

class Bar 
  include MongoMapper::EmbeddedDocument
  key :msg, String
end

Foo.delete_all

f = Foo.new(:msg => "first foo")
f.save!

puts "-- dump && load without bar"
foo = Foo.first()
foo_data = Marshal.dump(foo)
new_foo = Marshal.load(foo_data)
puts "foo == new_foo: #{foo == new_foo}"

puts "-- Adding Bar"
foo.bar = Bar.new(:msg => "i'm a bar")

foo_bar_data = Marshal.dump(foo)
new_foo_bar = Marshal.load(foo_bar_data)
puts "foo == new_foo_bar: #{foo == new_foo_bar}"
```

It crashes with the error

```
-- dump && load without bar
foo == new_foo: true
-- Adding Bar
mongo_marshal_test.rb:35:in `dump': no _dump_data is defined for class Proc (TypeError)
    from mongo_marshal_test.rb:35:in `<main>'
```

Dumping and loading works for the Document foo as long as there is no embedded bar. Can anybody tell me why this happens?

Obviously it's a feature of Bar. But I couldn't find a hint on how Marshal.dump works internally so I'm stuck...

I'm using ruby-2.0.0-p247, mongo_mapper 0.13.0.beta2, bson_ext 1.9.2.

Thanks folks...

Comment: (1) There's probably a `default_proc` or similar somewhere inside your model's MongoMapper stuff. (2) `Marshal` is not a good format for persistent data as the format can change when your Ruby version changes and there's no sane way to read an old Marshal dump in a newer Ruby. You'd probably have better luck with proper document embedding or serializing to JSON and using a Hash field for storage or something along those lines.

Comment: Hi, you're right. I don't want to persist it via dump(). I got this after putting the object into the (rails) session. So the ruby version is not the main problem.

Comment: The session is using Marshal behind your back. You'd usually put just the ID into the session, otherwise you'll have multiple copies of the same data and they can get out of sync.

Comment: Hi, you're right. I have a kind of weird design in that place. But none the less I wonder why it doesn't work. A hidden default proc is a good hint...

Comment: There are `default_proc`s all over the place. You could write your glue methods for Marshal, see the docs for details (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Marshal.html). I still think you should rethink your whole "put a whole MM object in the session" strategy.